# Trigonometry: Find the side of a triangle within a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Please help. I found a solution to this problem on yahoo answers but I do not understand the answer. I would use the laws of cosine but I have to be able to answer this without a calculator

**If AB = 14, BC = 12,
What is BD?**

[image: Oblong Triange]

So far since I know that angle ABC is a right triangle that line AC is equal to sqrt(52). Then I'd use the angle of CAD to get CD, finally with the Pythagorean theorem I get line DB. But this required me to use a calculator :[

Comment: what have you tried to solve this. Please show your effort, so we can help you in better way

Comment: Can you prove $$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{BC}{BD}$$ ?

Comment: Use similar Triangles on Triangle ABC and Triangle CBD.

Comment: So far since I know that angle ABC is a right triangle that line AC is equal to sqrt(52). Then I'd use the angle of CAD to get CD, finally with the Pythagorean theorem I get line DB. But this required me to use a calculator :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  $\triangle ABC, \dfrac{AB}{BC}=\sin\angle CAB,$

$\triangle  BCD,\dfrac{BC}{BD}=\sin\angle BCD$

But $\angle CAB=\angle BCD$

Comment: Thank you, answer was so simple I clearly needed more study. 

12/14=BD/12,
(12*12)/14=BD,
144/14=BD,
BD=72/7